# How much memory using for adaptive hash indexes in MariaDB?

Tags: index, mariadb, configuration

I'm reading about [`adaptive hash indexes`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-adaptive-hash.html) in MariaDB. It is created in memory, so it will be logically to know how much memory usually used for the index table.

For example, my local development database has only 2GB of RAM. Is it possible theoretically that adaptive index table will use > 50% of total memory?

I tried to search how much memory is usually used for AHI. But here is no info in the internet about memory and how to limit it. The only info I found is [`innodb-adaptive-hash-index-parts`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts). However here is no explanation about what means `a specific partition` and what is size of it?

Answer (score 0):

The main cache in RAM is `innodb_buffer_pool`.  On a tiny 2GB machine, that should be limited to maybe 500M.  And some other settings should be lowered, not raised.

It is probably best to let the engine decide how much to allocate for it.

And I doubt seriously that changing the default setting (8) for `innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts` will matter much.

MariaDB shows `Innodb_mem_adaptive_hash` in the BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY section of the `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` output.  Also in `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`

Comment: unfortunately, here is [no variable](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-status-variables/#innodb_mem_adaptive_hash) `Innodb_mem_adaptive_hash` in MySQL v10.4 :( (version that I'm using)

Comment: "10.4" is a MariaDB number, not MySQL.  What does `SELECT @@version;` say?

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that this will be matter, but yes, I'm using MariaDB.

Comment: Oops, I missed the fine print:  In MariaDB 5.5 and MariaDB 10.1, this system variable is present in XtraDB.
In MariaDB 10.2, MariaDB 10.3, and MariaDB 10.4, this system variable is not present.
In MariaDB 10.5, this system variable was reintroduced. -- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-status-variables/#innodb_mem_adaptive_hash

Comment: `MariaDB 10.4, this system variable is not present` ← this. So, the question how to get indexes memory size is still open...